# AWS Cognito SDK Node.JS Implementation

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am working on a server for an API that I am developing that is being built using node.js and requires the use of AWS Cognito. Before this, we developed a working version of this application on client side that used the AWS SDK, and I am currently trying to translate that functionality over to the server side. I am struggling to find a good way of doing this and have a few specific questions that, if answered, would probably allow me to get the implementation I am looking for. Basically, I want to know what the AWSCognito object is and how to access it like I see in the following line of code.

```
var poolData = { 
    UserPoolId : 'us-east-###########',
    ClientId : '########################'
};
var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
```

Currently my code is set up using the complete AWS SDK, installed using [a] and accessed in my code using [b].

```
[a] npm install --save aws-sdk
[b] var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

Is there a way to access this AWSCognito object from my AWS object? If so, how do I do that? If not, how do I get access to it/is it even possible to access it?

Edit: In broad summary, I just want access to the following functions and have no clue how to access them from a node.js server-

1. userPool.signUp(username, password, attributes, callback)
2. cognitoUser.confirmPassword(verification, newPassword, {})
3. cognitoUser.forgotPassword({})
4. cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {})
5. userPool.getCurrentUser()
6. cognitoUser.getSession(callback)
7. cognitoUser.confirmRegistration(verification, bool, callback)
8. cognitoUser.updateAttributes(attributeList, callback)
9. cognitoUser.getUserAttributes(callback)

Edit: Update 1

The AWSCognito object is something being set to a global variable in the window by the AWS Cognito SDK. This is a process that only works client-side (yes I know there are hacky solutions to emulate a window on my server, I would prefer not to use these). Is there an equivalent object on server side that I can access and call functions from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Cognito in a Node.JS environment, but doing so with the AWS SDK for JavaScript is a bit different from doing so with the AWS Cognito SDK. Based on the names of the functions you want to access, you should take a look at the [Cognito Identity Provider Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html). Operations that start with `admin` are meant to be called from a server using AWS credentials.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I had looked over that documentation already, but didn't really understand what the purpose of the 'admin' operations were. Thank you!